# NoClassDefFoundError when implementing a UnaryOperator as an anonymous class

Tags: java, collections, java-8, functional-programming

The question that i solved is as follows:

> Given a list of non-negative integers, return an integer list of the
> rightmost digits.
>
> rightDigit([1, 22, 93]) → [1, 2, 3] rightDigit([16, 8, 886, 8, 1]) →
> [6, 8, 6, 8, 1] rightDigit([10, 0]) → [0, 0]

*The question itself is trivial, which i solved using a single line stream operation.*

```
return nums.stream().map(e -> e % 10).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However, just to test my understanding of Anonymous classes, i decided to implement this using an Anonymous class, coming up with is:

```
public List<Integer> rightDigit(List<Integer> nums) {
    nums.replaceAll(new java.util.function.UnaryOperator<Integer>() {
        public Integer apply(Integer n) {
            return  new Integer(n.intValue() % 10);
        }
    });  
    return nums;
}
```

My problem here is that i'm getting a **NoClassDefFoundError** error and have been unable to resolve it on my own. I'd be grateful to know what i'm doing wrong here, thanks.

Comment: Can you put the full stacktrace which class is not found?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Works for me. What class is not found in your case? `Exception in ... java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:` What is behind the colon in your case?

Comment: @AxelRichter It's a question from the website codingbat.java, their compilation error is limited to NoClassDefFoundError:Shell$1 and there's no way to print the stack trace. I think that it this error must be related to that particular website's Java environment

Comment: Note that `replaceAll` is not equivalent to the stream operation (and that change is unrelated to your change from lambda expression to an anonymous inner class).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It compiles correctly.

It looks like the definition of UnaryOperator is not in your classpath.

Could you please share: the full stack trace, `java --version` and how you compile and run it.

Comment: It's a question from the website codingbat.java, their compilation error is limited to NoClassDefFoundError:Shell$1 and there's no way to print the stack trace. I think that it this error must be related to that particular website's Java environment.

Comment: @Gestalt `Shell$1` looks precisely like the anonymous inner class. So it’s indeed an issue of that environment.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for confirming. Any idea what the issue might be on their side or is it too much of a "blackbox" to guess with such limited information?

Comment: @Gestalt we can only make an educated guess. This likely is something like “run the compiler, copy the resulting class file, run the app from the target location” or the dynamic variant, “run the compiler, read the class file manually and create a runtime class, use the class”. I just tried the site and it seem to run a naïve check for the `class` keyword, rejecting source containing it, but does not account for `interface`, `enum`, or anonymous classes…